# Maven: Java classes don't compile after Ant task

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, maven-plugin, mojo

My project generates source code using the [Rats! parser generator](http://cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/xtc/). Rats! doesn't have a Maven plugin that I'm aware of, so I'm trying to build the parser using an Ant Java
task, like so:

```
 <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <phase>generate-sources</phase>
       <configuration>
         <tasks>
           <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/" />
           <java classpath="lib/xtc.jar" classname="xtc.parser.Rats">
             <arg line="-in ${project.build.sourceDirectory}" />
             <arg line="-out ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/" />
             <arg path="${project.build.sourceDirectory}/Dot.rats" />
           </java>
         </tasks>
         <sourceRoot>
           ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java
         </sourceRoot>
       </configuration>
       <goals>
         <goal>run</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

The details of what Rats! does aren't important: the end result is that
the above generates `Dot.java` and places it in
`target/generated-sources/main/java`. It works fine.

The problem is that, with this `plugin` element in my `pom.xml`, none of
the Java files in the project get compiled.

I generated a project
using "`mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=foo -DartifactId=bar`" and added the
file `src/main/java/Dot.rats`:

```
module Dot;

public void Dot = "." !_ ;
```

(This is a grammar that accepts only files with a single dot.)

If I run "`mvn compile`" without the `plugin` element, I get:

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bar
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to
/home/chris/src/tests/maven/project1/bar/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 01 18:57:08 EDT 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/67M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where the one Java file being compiled is `src/main/java/foo/App.java`, a Java class created by the archetype (i.e., not a generated source file).

If I do "`mvn clean`" then add the `plugin` element invoking Rats!, I get:

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bar
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]
[INFO] Executing tasks
   [mkdir] Created dir:
/home/chris/src/tests/maven/project1/bar/target/generated-sources/main/java
Rats! Parser Generator, v. 1.14.2, (C) 2004-2008 Robert Grimm
Processing /home/chris/src/tests/maven/project1/bar/src/main/java/Dot.rats ...
```

I.e., Maven is running Rats! (which is not failing, AFAICT) but not compiling *any* Java classes, not even the pre-existing class `App.java`. After the run, I have `target/generated-sources/main/java/Dot.java` but no `target/classes`.

I've tried other kinds of Ant tasks and they don't interfere with Java
compilation. For example, if I replace the task element above with an
echo task

```
<tasks>
  <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/" />
  <echo file="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/Dot.java">
     public class Dot { }
  </echo>
</tasks>
```

I get

```
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bar
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [antrun:run {execution: default}]
[INFO] Executing tasks
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] Registering compile source root
/home/chris/src/tests/maven/project1/bar/target/generated-sources/main/java
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [compiler:compile]
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to
/home/chris/src/tests/maven/project1/bar/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 01 19:03:34 EDT 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/79M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Obviously there's something I'm not understanding about how Maven
executes the `java` task. Is there something simple that I'm doing
wrong? Is there an alternative way to accomplish this task that I
should try (perhaps a more "Maven-native" way)?

[UPDATE] Funny story. I tried replacing the Ant task with a Maven plugin, by writing a `RatsMojo` class that invokes `xtc.parser.Rats` directly and replacing the `plugin` element above with

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>edu.nyu.xtc</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-xtc-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>rats</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</inputDirectory>
          <outputDirectory> ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java</outputDirectory>
          <grammarFile>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/Dot.rats</grammarFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

It does the exact same thing: it runs Rats! then terminates without compiling *any* of the Java files in the project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that Rats! calls `System.exit()` (or similar), terminating the JVM. I would have thought that Ant would wrap this (the java task is copied over from a `build.xml` and it doesn't terminate the Ant build), but the following works by forcing the Rats! process into a separate JVM:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
      <argument>-classpath</argument>
      <argument>${basedir}/lib/xtc.jar</argument>
      <argument>xtc.parser.Rats</argument>
      <argument>-in</argument>
      <argument>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</argument> 
      <argument>-out</argument>
      <argument>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/</argument>
      <argument>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/Dot.rats</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or, just add `fork="true"` to the `java` task in the `antrun` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the new directory to the maven source directories. It can be done using the [buildhelper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/). Add this to your pom:

```
  <build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java/</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question: it's not compiling *any* Java files. Not the generated files and not the files that were there to begin with. The sourceRoot element does add the generated sources directory to the compile path (e.g., the generated files do get compiled in the echo example).

Comment: I should add that I did try adding this plugin configuration and it didn't change anything: still no Java compilation.